# scanf() - getting field count and checking for EOF

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to parse and convert a csv and thought I'd try my hand at c since I'm currently learning the language.

```
int main()
{
  char * s1, * s2;
  int field_count = 0;
  while ((field_count = scanf("%20[^;];%s", s1, s2)) != EOF)
  {
    printf("%d\n", field_count));
    if (field_count != 2)
      continue;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I don't get why `field_count` is always 0 no matter how many fields there are in each line, and the loop never ends either.

I tried changing the while clause to:

```
while ((field_count = scanf("%s", s1)) != EOF)
```

but it made no difference.

I've tried googling, but examples retaining the return value AND checking for EOF were hard to find.

Comment: You should define `s1` and `s2` with a storage: `char s1[1024], s2[1024]; `. Another problem is that EOF is a "special character". scanf returns the number of value successfully read. Testing this number against EOF doesn't make sense. Your scanf format string is also bogus. If you want to read two strings, it should at least have 2 %s. You want to loop while file_count == 2, I guess. Otherwise your program will never end.

Comment: From what I've read, EOF is often defined as -1 even though this is platform-dependant. I got it to work now. Your suggestion of defining the chars as arrays instead helped.

Comment: Indeed scanf returns -1 when the input is ctrl-D which is the keyboard equivalent of EOF.

Comment: However may comment about the invalid scanf format string is not correct. It should work if the second field doesn't contain white spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of code that should work.
It allocates a storage buffer for s1 and s2. 
This code expects that the fields are at most 99 characters long.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  char s1[100], s2[100];
  int field_count = 0;
  while ((field_count = scanf("%99[^;];%99[^\n]", s1, s2)) >= 0)
  {
    printf("%d '%s' '%s'\n", field_count, s1, s2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Scanf is a bit limited to parse an input string. You might get unexpected result when you give it an empty string.